# Variable in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, variables, laravel-5

I have a method to get an author and display it on a form. It also retrieves the number of quotes attributed to that author. Being pedantic I do not wish to have "1 quotes" so I wrote the following in my layout:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboardmaster')

$quotetext = "quotes";

if ( $quotes == 1)
    { $quotetext = "quote"; }



@section('pageheading')
    <div class="well">
        <h2><i class = "fa fa-quote-left"></i> edit author ({{$author->author}}), ({{ number_format($quotes,0) }} {{}}$quotetext }}) </h2>
    </div>
@endsection
```

but I am now getting an error saying

```
Undefined variable: quotetext
```

It is clearly defined and I have also tried replacing {{ with

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

needs to be

```
<?php $quotetext = "quotes";

if ( $quotes == 1)
    { $quotetext = "quote"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs to look like this:

```
@extends('layouts.dashboardmaster')

<?php $quotetext = "quotes"; ?>

@if($quotetext == 1)
    <?php $quotetext = "quote"; ?>
@endif

@section('pageheading')
    <div class="well">
        <h2><i class = "fa fa-quote-left"></i> edit author ({{$author->author}}), ({{ number_format($quotes,0) }} {{$quotetext }}) </h2>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't put php codes in `<?php` tag. 
put them in php tag and everything will be fine

```
<?php
$quotetext = "quotes";
if ( $quotes == 1){
     $quotetext = "quote"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

```
{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

so

```
{{ isset($quotetext) ?: "quotes" }}

@if ($quotes == 1)
    {{ $quotetext = "quote"; }}
@endif
```

but i think u will get an error about `$quotes` aswell, anyway remember this is blade not normal php

Answer (score 0):

Use localization provided by Laravel. See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization#pluralization) for more information.

Just as an example, add this to your language file (for example `resources/lang/en/lang.php`

```
return [
    'quote' => 'quote|quotes',
]
```

Then use this in your view:

```
{{ trans_choice('lang.quote', $count) }}
```